# Get All Sections in a Notebook

Tags: onenote-api

I can get all the sections in a Notebook using the OneNote API using the following

```
 https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/{notebookId}/sections
```

But cannot find a reference to the syntax when using the MSGraph API.

I've a number of combinations, but all give Bad Request msgs.

I'm using the Graph Explorer with MS Graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{id}/sections
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge,  That works. Still waiting for a good UWP OneNote API sample that uses MSGraph.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=uwp+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories

I think this might be what you're looking for :)